# How to detect when a Notification Tray was pulled down and Dismissed in Xamarin Form iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Why does "applicationDidBecomeActive" and "applicationWillResignActive" both get called when i pull down the Notification Tray in Xamarin forms ios?

I want an action to happen when the notification tray is pulled down and another action when the notification tray is dismissed..

DidEnterBackground and WillEnterForeground are not invoked in this cases..

How do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it seems a bug in iOS as I can reproduce this issue in XCode.

This issue has been mentioned several times. I find several links which might be a little help. Kevin van Mierlo purposed a workaround in this [didBecomeActiveNotification Gets Called One-time Unexpectedly When User Swipe Down the Notification Center Screen on iOS Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215679/uiapplication-didbecomeactivenotification-gets-called-one-time-unexpectedly-when).

Also, I find this [UIApplicationDelegate receive applicationDidBecomeActive when pulling down notification center](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/94777) at Apple Developer Forum. min60.com purposed a workaround that prevent running code in applicationDidBecomeActive. It seems that this issue remains till now and you could join them for discussion.