# applicationDidBecomeActive get called when iPhone's Lock Screen button is pressed

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

In my app , I check `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].changeCount` in

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

But I found that every time I press  iPhone's Lock Screen button , this `applicationDidBecomeActive` will be called , and the changeCount value will alway be `0` this time

Why the `applicationDidBecomeActive` called for Lock Screen ? (My OS version is iOS16.1)

Comment: Others have noticed the same unexpected behavior. Possible workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71584704/795339

Answer (score 0):

In my situation , I use this code to avoid the paste board check in locking screen(In fact ,the `pasteboardChangeCount` will be zero when `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called in Lock Screen )

```
- (void)checkPasteBoard
{
    static NSInteger lastCount = 0;
    NSInteger pasteboardChangeCount = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].changeCount;
    if (lastCount != pasteboardChangeCount && pasteboardChangeCount != 0)
    {
        lastCount = pasteboardChangeCount;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
```